# can't move_uploaded_file to folder

Tags: php, mysql, image, path

I can insert the folder path into the database but the picture file doesn't seem to move into that folder?

```
$pic = $_POST['pic'];

$picName= $_FILES['pic']['name'];

$type = $_FILES['pic']['type'];

$tmp = $_FILES['pic']['tmp'];

$picPath = "/pictures/";

  if(is_uploaded_file($tmp)) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $picPath . $picName)) {
            echo "congrats! Image is uploaded.";
        }
        else {
            echo "Sorry, couldn't move your picture.";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry, couldn't upload your picture.";
    }

$picPath = $picPath . $picName;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO User(pic) VALUES ('$picPath')");
```

I get this echo message: Sorry, couldn't upload your picture.

**The php files is saved on public_html folder, and I have a pictures folder where I want to move the users pictures into.**

The insertion works as I can store the $picPath in my database, but the picture don't get stored in my folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$tmp = $_FILES['pic']['tmp'];
```

with

```
$tmp = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: thank you. I do not know why 'tmp_name' worked and not 'tmp'. Although I suspect it is a keyword needed.

Comment: These arrays are set up by PHP, it has to be 'tmp_name', because that's just how PHP does it

Answer (score 1):

1) check folder permissions if its writable or not.  
2) make sure your path is same with the same folder name in code as well. 
3) Try to change from this `$picPath = "/pictures/";` to something like this `$picPath = "pictures/";` removed forward slash.